# Создание строки из значений (процедура)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

Добрый день. Т.к. от программирования далек, но в виду производственной необходимости в это дело ввязался, прошу помочь с написанием процедуры в `oracle plsql developer` (буду признателен за помощь в создании алгоритма так же).

Суть такова - есть первый столбец (условно `ID`, в моем контексте не уникальный), и второй столбец, назову его "признаком". В базе это хранится в таком виде

```
ID  Признак
1   Красный
1   Темно-красный
2   Синий
2   Бирюзовый
```

Необходимо написать процедуру такого рода - все признаки, соответствующие одинаковому `ID`, пишутся в одну ячейку. Т.е. так:

```
ID   Признак (применение процедуры)
1    Красный, (или ;) Темно-красный
2    Синий, Бирюзовый
```

Буду крайне признателен за помощь!
В виду необходимости скидываю сам кусок селекта:

```
(case when (row_number() over(partition by
    (select dd.name from metrology.document dd where dd.id in (select **max(d.document_id)** from metrology.eqtype_document d where d.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = e.id))
    order by e.name)) = 1 then
    (select dd.name from metrology.document dd where dd.id in (select **max(d.document_id)** from metrology.eqtype_document d where d.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = e.id)) end) as doc_name_to_form
```

Символами ** отмечен участок кода, из за которого возникает весь сыр-бор. 
Max там включен чисто для работоспособности - данный участок селекта возвращает более одной строки и вызывает ошибку ora, поэтому я его max-ом искуссвенно урезал до одного возвращаемого результата. Но дело в том, что в 70% случаев данный участок должен возвращать более одного значения, для чего и необходима конкатенация, и я не знаю, как сюда инъектировать какой либо код.

Comment: А как вы уже пробовали? Что не получается? Или вы хотите, чтобы за Вас написали всю процедуру?

Comment: Я пробовал через оператор LISTAGG - но при его использовании мне выдается ошибка ORA-00904.
Нет, всю процедуру мне писать не надо, а вот за описание алгоритма был бы благодарен.

Comment: Напишите Ваше решение

Comment: (case when (row_number() over(partition by
 (select listagg(dd.name, ', ') from metrology.document dd where dd.id in (select (d.document_id) from metrology.eqtype_document d where d.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = e.id))
 order by e.name)) = 1 then
 (select listagg(dd.name, ', ') from metrology.document dd where dd.id in (select (d.document_id) from metrology.eqtype_document d where d.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = e.id)) end) as doc_name_to_form, (строка селекта, которую необходимо заменить процедурой)

       
Узнал почему у меня не работает LISTAGG - он доступен с 11 oracle, у меня используется 9.

Comment: Порядок после группировки важен?

Comment: Нет, при необходимости доработаю сам - главное, чтобы результат получился как при использовании оператора LISTAGG.

Comment: Почему обязательно должна быть процедура?

Comment: Необязательно, просто я в меру своих скудных знаний области пришел к выводу, что лучше заменить процедурой. Если можно это дело выполнить селектом в 9 оракле - я только рад буду)

Comment: @n0n4m3 Версия Oracle какая ? `With` поддерживается ?

Comment: @Mike - oracle 9. With поддерживается.

Comment: А с какой целью вы те подзапросы, где у вас ошибка пытались применить ?

Comment: В итоге должен получиться (и он получается, просто урезанный до 1))) список вроде документ1 документ2 документ3. Такое решение связано с тем, что данный список будет использоваться в печатной пользовательской форме, но из за корявого самописного дизайнера форм в клиентской программе, в котором нет ряда очень важных базовых функций, для нормального отображения форм при выводе на клиенте приходится придумывать обходные решения в уже в селектах.

Comment: @n0n4m3 я смотрю Ваш запрос, и мне кажется странным такое решение. Если я правильно понял логику, то в условии `case` написано `если количество документов с таким именем = 1, тогда выведем имя этого документа, иначе ничего выводить не будем`. Где звездочки, у Вас написана валидная конструкция с `in`, которая плохо обрабатывается дальше. Возможно Вы решаете проблемы не с той стороны? Я правильно понимаю, что приведенный вами запрос просто должен перечислить документы через запятую?

Comment: @lDrakonl, именно так, но я не знаю, как применить сюда конкатенацию, ибо если убрать 'max' - возникает ошибка о возврате более одной строки. Страшный он такой отчасти потому что id и названия хранятся не в одной таблице.

Comment: А у вас в строку какие документы должны получиться? Сейчас выглядит, что в строку должны быть документы не только с одинаковым `id`(как написано в вопросе), а все документы для которых выполняется условие `metrology.eqtype_document d where  d.EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID = e.id`

Comment: @lDrakonl все верно - документ не должен повторяться.

Comment: Хм, мой вопрос был не в повторении. В самом вопросе у вас написано, что для разных ID получатся разные строчки. Но глядя на запрос кажется, что в строку должно было получиться `красный, темно-красный,синий, бирюзовый`. Вы бы дополнили вопрос содержимым реальных таблиц и результатом, который должен из них получится. А то я запутался

Comment: Система не позволяет нам перейти в чат из-за малой репутации у вас. Найдите меня в телеграме по такому же нику(@ldrakonl), если есть возможность, и мы решим эту проблему намного быстрее)

Comment: сейчас пробую sys_connect_by_path, если ничего хорошего не выйдет - я вам напишу, спасибо

Comment: @n0n4m3 вы там примите ответ Mike. Вроде он вам подошел. Галочка напротив ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, если не заработают wm_conat или sys_xmlagg, сборка рекурсивным CTE:

```
with Src(ID, Color, RN) as(
  select ID, Color, row_number() over(partition by ID order by NULL) RN
    from tab
),
Tree(ID,color,RN) as(
  select ID, Color, RN from Src where RN=1
  union all
  select T.ID,T.Color||','||S.Color,S.RN
    from Tree T, Src S
   where S.ID=T.ID and S.RN=T.RN+1
)
select * from Tree
```

Или такой вариант (при наличии sys_connect_by_path):

```
select ID, substr(max(sys_connect_by_path(Color,',')),2)
  from (
        select ID, Color, row_number() over(partition by ID order by NULL) RN
          from tab
  )
  start with RN=1
  connect by ID=prior ID and RN=prior RN+1
  group by Id
```

Или сделать функцию, получающую строку по ID, что возможно удобнее для применения в выходных формах:

```
create or replace function get_colors(ID_ number) return varchar2
is
  result varchar2(4000);
begin
  result:=NULL;
  for C in(select accname from v1users where vidid=ID_) loop
    if length(result)+length(C.accname) > 3996 then
      return substr(result||',...',2);
    end if;
    result:=result||','||C.accname;
  end loop;
  return substr(result,2);
end;
```

Comment: а чем подход через `connect by` лучше `wm_concat` или `xml`? Мне казалось, что `connect by` работает довольно медленно, а результат получается один и тот же.

Comment: @lDrakonl Не думаю, что он лучше, это на случай если ТС не хочет использовать wm_concat как недокументированную и sys_xmlagg у него не пойдет, как не пошел listagg

Comment: @Mike, решение с sys_connect_by_path было самым близким - но в ответ мне "вылезла" ошибка "результат конкатенации слишком велик"). В типе varchar2 нельзя снять ограничение на количество символов?)

Comment: @n0n4m3 Нельзя. А вообще мне кажется, что вывод в печатную форму списка из более 2000 символов как то многовато. Может ограничить кол-во выводимых значений

Comment: @n0n4m3 В принципе, если вы хотите вставить этот вывод в неком и так сложном запросе, в котором при этом эти цвета отдельными строками сейчас не выбираются, то конечно может и проще сделать функцию, которая получит на вход ID и вернет на выходе все цвета по нему. правда вернет то она все равно varchar2 и значит в ней будут те же проблемы, но там будет легче контролировать длину и в случае достижения некого предела написать '...' и остановится

Comment: @Mike, а можете в общих чертах показать, как будет выглядеть функция подобного рода? Я, к сожалению, с функциями и процедурами дела не имел, необходимое загуглю, но мне нужен хотя бы "логический" каркас.

Comment: @n0n4m3 Сделал функцию. В названии параметра подчеркивание, что бы не конфликтовал с названиями колонок в таблице.

Comment: @Mike, большое спасибо - доделал вашу функцию под свои нужды, результат получился как раз требуемый. Всем спасибо за советы и помощь!

Comment: @Mike,. я бы с радостью - пишет что у меня недостаточно репутации (треб. 15). Обещаю, если когда нибудь будет 15 репутации - вернусь сюда и поставлю плюс:)

Answer (score 2):

Получить нужный результат можно таким запросом:

```
select id, 
       to_char(wm_concat("Признак")) as "Признак" 
from   table
group  by id
```

Следует заметить, что `wm_concat` функция недокументированная и в проме ее использовать не всегда разумно. 
Если `wm_concat` не подходит, можно использовать `XML`:

```
select id, 
       CAST(RTRIM(Sys_xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(col, id||', ')).extract('/ROWSET/COL/text()').getclobval(), ', ') AS VARCHAR2(4000)) as "Признак"
FROM   table
group  by id
```

`col` - это Ваша колонка `Признак`. Использовать русское наименование колонки у меня не получилось. В обоих вариантах могут быть проблемы с сортировкой значений.

Comment: Именно поэтому я и решил попробовать решить вопрос процедурой)

Comment: Дополнил ответ решением без wm_concat

Comment: добавил свой селект в первый пост в теме с описанием - если не затруднит - посмотрите, как ваш код можно применить в моем случае.

Comment: У вас там написано что-то страшное. Как вы хотели применить мои запросы, какой результат надо получить для всего большого запроса?

Comment: в стартовом топике все подробное описание.
Если еще раз коротко - данный селект работает корректно, но возвращает более одной строки, из за чего в участке, отмеченном ** посредством 'max' я урезал результат до одного значения (чисто для временной работоспособности, не логической правильности). Вместо этого костыля я хотел придумать решение, которое будет конкатенировать возвращаемые строки в одну посредством процедуры, т.е. мне нужно изобрести LISTAGG на 9 оракле каким либо способом. wm_concat не сработал.

Comment: А что значит `wm_concat` не сработал? У Вас нет такой функции? И как обстоят дела с `Sys_xmlagg` ?

Comment: при применение wm_concat в нужном месте возникает ora-904. Sys_xmlagg - не понимаю, как его применить в моем случае.